# How to dynamically calculate and display total at last row using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 10 text boxes the below java script is working fine if all text box is display (dynamic total is display at the end of row). if I need to show only particular text boxes like i need only 3 boxes means the dynamic total is not working at the end row. Can some one suggest me how to do based on number of responses.

```
<script name="question.after" wrap="ready"><![CDATA[
    setInterval(function(){
        var sum1 = 0; 
        val1 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.0").value)
        val2 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.1").value)
        val3 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.2").value)
        val4 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.3").value)
        val5 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.4").value)
        val6 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.5").value)
        val7 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.6").value)
        val8 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.7").value)
        val9 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.8").value)
        val10 = Number(document.getElementById("ans1103.0.9").value)
        if (val1 > 0)    
        {
        sum1=sum1+val1
        }
        if (val2 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val2
        }
        if (val3 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val3
        }
        if (val4 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val4
        }
        if (val5 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val5
        }
        if (val6 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val6
        }
        if (val7 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val7
        }
        if (val8 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val8
        }
        if (val9 > 0)
        {
        sum1=sum1+val9
        }
        document.getElementById("ans1103.0.9").value = sum1;   
    },1);
]]></script>
```

Comment: How do you determine which boxes are shown?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean all textboxes are showing, but you only want to sum those that have a value entered? Or do you mean that some textboxes will not be showing at certain times (and you don't want to add their values)?

Comment: If you use a class to hide and show the textboxes, you can check the class. Things will be much easier if you use a loop instead of 10 different variables.

Comment: Are you using CSS "display:none" to hide the textboxes? If so, then you wont be able to access them using "document.getElementById" as they are removed from the document I believe. (you could instead set the opacity of the textboxes to 0 when you want to hide them.(or some other workaround)

Comment: Yes I have used disabled=True; in script, so this wont work

Comment: I have one check box question in my form, based on that question I have to consider the textbox and show the running total for that particular boxes

Comment: Can some one help me how to display total without using disabled=True